# How to add color to text in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, colorama

None of the answers on the internet helped me...

First, I imported colorama

`from colorama import Fore`

Then, I tried coloring the text...

`print(Fore.GREEN + 'some text')`

But, instead of colouring the text, it does this crap:

`[32msome text`

instead of green

can anyone help me?

Comment: Your terminal does not recognize the escape sequences for color. Please spefiy your software environment and OS.

Comment: Did you remember to call `colorama.init()` first?

Comment: Are you running your script from the command line? If you're doing this inside an IDLE interactive prompt or something, it's probably not going to work. In Windows, Colorama chiefly interfaces with the cmd window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Future Reference

Steps to install colorama

run cmd as ADMINISTRATOR

type `pip install colorama`

and boom. there you go

---

How to use:

Open the **COMMAND LINE**, not **IDLE**

Use the command listed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

the use for this case is

**the_scape_character[formate_code;text_color_code;background_color_code**

you can express the scape code in hexadecimal ("\x1b"),octal("\033") or with a **chr(27)**

you can use an **ANSI** code to change the color in the print

```
print(chr(27)+"[33m"+"yellow text")
```

in this case 33m is the yellow color you need see the documentation for the other text colors and the backgrounds colors

```
Black = 30;Red = 31;Green = 32
```